# Sharepoint Foundation 2010 development environment installation problems

Tags: windows-7, installation, development-environment, sharepoint-2010, foundation

I'm having problems installing development machine for Sharepoint (Foundation) 2010. This is what I did so far on the same machine:

1. Installed a clean Windows 7 x64 with 4GB of RAM without being part of any domain. Just a simple standalone machine.
2. Enabled IIS related features as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee554869(v=office.14)) except IIS6 related ones (two of them)
3. Installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Development Edition (DB Engine and Writer being enabled but not SQL Agent)
4. Installed Visual Studio 2010 Premium
5. Started installing Sharepoint Foundation 2010 with first extracting files, changing config to enable Windows 7 installation and then installed it as Server Farm (then Complete) to avoid installing SQL Express.
6. Created a separate SPF_CONFIG local user with `Logon on as a service` right.
7. Opened SPF Management Shell and run `New-SPConfigurationDatabase` so I am able to use a non-domain username (SPF_CONFIG that I created in the previous step)

But all I get is this:
[image: Unknown error]

The outcome after this error is:

- Database `Sharepoint2010Config` is created
- User SPF_CONFIG is added to SQL Server and attached to this newly created database as `dbowner`

[image]

- Checking SQL server security logins this user has following rights:

  - `dbcreator`
  - `securityadmin`
  - `public`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Resolved it myself after trying all kinds of things

The main thing is I haven't given up and installed stadalone installation.
I've followed two guides:

- [this blog post](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/installing-sharepoint-2010-privilege-service-accounts/)
- and [this MSDN resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx)

Step by step instructions I followed (may be helpful to someone else as well):

1. Then I've uninstalled SPF2010
2. Setup all accounts as described in the first document
3. Reinstalled all prerequisites and KBs described in MSDN resource.
4. Cancelled configuration wizard and ran Sharpoint PowerShell
5. Executed
   `New-SPConfigurationDatabase -AdministrationContentDatabaseName "SomeDBName"`
6. Command than asked me about all other missing info
7. Waited for the command to finish (few minutes)
8. And it succeeded
9. FINALLY!
10. Rerun `psconfigui` and finished configuration
11. Successfully launched SPF Admin Web.

*clap clap clap*